# should the "definition" and "legal-terms" tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

As per the title, [definition](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition)'s usage guidance is "*for questions that seek to clarify the meaning of a term*." As this is LawSE it seems to me that the only terms that require defining are legal ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> should the "definition" and "legal-terms" tags be merged?

No. Users might need help understanding the relevance or scope of a word in statutes or clauses, but that does not necessarily render that specific word an instance of legal terminology.

Likewise, courts oftentimes resort to the commonplace meaning of crucial words when justifying their interpretation of some text(s) relevant to a controversy. When doing so, they typically quote definitions from sources other than legislation or legal dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks, a clear and concise argument for the defence. I'll give it a bit longer for others to express an opinion, but if yours is the consensus I'll edit the Usage Guidance for both tags to properly reflect their differences.

Answer (score 2):

Bump...

For those with sufficient reputation there is a [pending tag synonym proposal](https://law.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested) for [legal-terms](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-terms) and [definition](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition).

I have voted to decline the proposal in light of the valid points raised in Iñaki Viggers' answer.